# SQL Server データベースの初期サイズを小さくしたい

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server のデータベースを使用しています。
トランザクションログではなく、テーブル内のレコードが多くなったので、不要なレコードを削除しました。(DELETE文)
しかしmdfファイルのサイズが変わりませんでした。

そこで圧縮も試みましたが、圧縮はデータベースの初期サイズより小さいサイズへの圧縮はできないと[MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-2017)に記載がありました。

ここで本題ですが、この初期サイズを小さくすることはできないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

[データベースの作成 | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) からコードを引用します。

```
USE master ;  
GO  
CREATE DATABASE Sales  
ON   
( NAME = Sales_dat,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\saledat.mdf',  
    SIZE = 10,  
    MAXSIZE = 50,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5 )  
LOG ON  
( NAME = Sales_log,  
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\salelog.ldf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;  
GO
```

このように `CREATE DATABASE` を実行する際に、`SIZE`(ファイルサイズ), `MAXSIZE`(ファイルサイズの上限), `FILEGROWTH`(自動拡張するときの増加量) を指定出来ます。

`SIZE` の値を小さくすれば、初期サイズを小さく出来るのではと思いますのでお試しください。より詳しいことはTransact-SQLのリファレンスをご確認ください。

Comment: 可能かは別として、質問の意図は「既存のデータベース」が対象ではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、そういう意図でしたか・・・。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。htb様のおっしゃる通り、既存のDBが対象となります。Create時ではありません…